# Acessing earlier values using scipy's odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I am solving a system of differential equations using scipy's odeint and I have a problem now that I can't seem to fix:
if a certain condition is met, I have to 'go back in time' to an earlier state, change a (global) parameter and continue integrating from there.

At first I thought, although you can't really go back in time with odeint that I will store the time(s) at which the condition is met, change the state of the system (the variable that is integrated) and just continue the integration from there.
Unfortunately I can't find a way to access the values of the variable for past times from within odeint. Does somebody know a way to solve my dilemma?

If that is not possible, can somebody suggest a different way to do this? Performance is an issue, so I would really like to not have to write my own solver in python. I could do it in C, but that would require me to change the whole implementation and that would cost me a lot of time.

Comment: Is the time of the earlier state fixed, is it given by some equation of the state or does it depend on the final state of the first integration? Why not repeat the first integration until the earlier state, then continue from there? It is generally not advisable to implement complicated control logic in the derivatives function, normally that does not play well with the internal adaptive step size control. Matlab has "events", I do not recall a similar mechanism in the standard scipy ode solvers.

Comment: On mimicking events in python: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/01/28/Mimicking-ode-events-in-python/, another relevant question promoting the SUNDIALS package and pyDStool: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16325/dynamically-ending-ode-integration-in-scipy

Comment: It is not exactly fixed in time. It is basically like this: The differential equation is to be evaluated at 10^6 timepoints, and at every 100th timepoint, we check for the condition. If it is true, we go back 100 timepoints, but only then. Which is also why I don't like the option of splitting up the integration - It would be a pretty large loop that probably would lose the efficiency advantage of odeint.